# How does R calculate joint significance parameters DCCA1 and DCCB1 when conducting a DCC GARCH analysis?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, garch

I have conducted my DCCGARCH analysis using the RMGARCH package. Printing the function dccfit provides each of the parameters for the univariate models, but also joint signifiance parameters **dcca1** and **dccb1**.

I know the assumptions and the theory of why both should be significant, and have used it. But I don't know the underlying theory that R uses to calculate these parameters? I would like to justify checking these parameters in my paper with sources, so I am looking for any references as to where these parameters are derived from. Is it an F-statistic or are there other methods used here? Also, any links to a research paper I can use to justify these parameters? Any help is greatly appreciated!

(Also, the documentation about rmgarch doesnt state dcca1 dccb1 parameters or joint significance parameters as far as i found)